# javascript consolidating switch statement

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

I have the following:

```
switch(state) {
  case MyStates.StateA:
     //do something
     break;
  case MyStates.StateB:
     //do something
     break;
  case MyStates.StateC:
     //do something
     break;
```

}

Say `StateB` and `StateC` both need to process the same bit of code, how can I avoid the duplication?  Note that I *cannot* set `MyStates.StateB = MyStates.StateC`; they have to differ and can also be of different types.  I want to do something like the following illegal statement:

```
case MyStates.StateB || case MyStates.StateC :
```

Comment: HINT: The `break` keyword is used to stop fall-through.
http://javascript.about.com/od/hintsandtips/a/fallthrough.htm

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
switch(state) {
  case MyStates.StateA:
     //do something for A
     break;
  case MyStates.StateB:
  case MyStates.StateC:
     //do something for B and C
     break;
}
```

Comment: For completeness, you should also include the default: / break; block as well.